# Build Pipeline keep crashing at Publish level of Azure Functions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, .net-5

I am trying to build and deploy an Azure Function using Devops Pipeline (CI)

These are my steps

[image]

[image]

But everything till step Publish executing without any error. But at the Publish level I am getting this error (As in the image above)

```
Active code page: 65001
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.
Finishing: Publish
```

I thought its because of .Net version thats why I have added Use .NET 5.x step just before publish. But it still triggering the same error.

Here is the Yaml of these 3 steps

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2   displayName: 'dotnet build'   inputs:
    projects: 'Toolset/ScheduledJobs/*.csproj'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2   displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 5.x'   inputs:
    version: 5.x


steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2   displayName: Publish   inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingdirectory)/ScheduledJobs'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false
```

Please let me know what I did wrong there?

I developed the Azure Function (3.0) in VS 2019

Comment: You didn't specify a path containing your project to the publish step. Look at your build step versus your publish step.

Comment: Move also use .NET SDK step before dotnet restore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you publish you need provide path to the project like here:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    projects: 'BlazorSample.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/stackoverflow/51-blazor-sample/BlazorSample
```

Please notice `working directory` at the end.

Also change your order bu putting

```
- task: UseDotNet@2   displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 5.x'   inputs:
    version: 5.x
```

before this:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2   displayName: 'dotnet build'   inputs:
    projects: 'Toolset/ScheduledJobs/*.csproj'
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. I really missed that point.. Saved my day...

Comment: @SandeepThomas can you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?